# scroll into negative margin

Tags: css, overflow, margin

tl;dr:  If you have an element with a negative margin-top, can you make it so the scroll bar allows you to scroll into the negative part?

Hello,
I have a page with cards that need to expand both up and down (if your curious and lucky, it might be up at http://www.biologicalspeculation.com/context.cgi )

The way I accomplish the "expand up" is to have matching transitions such that the height expands at the same time as the margin-top of the containing div moves negative.  This makes for a smooth animation, but it means the containing div gets a increasingly negative margin, and eventually goes off the page, and you can't scroll to it.  I tried adding an intermediate div with overflow:scroll, but it had the same problem as the body overflow.

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have it so that the card just expand in height to fit the content but you use [jQuery to scroll the browser](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/) so the view port stays on the expanded card instead of using negative margins?